# How to reduce csv file size in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I had a csv file of 8 million rows. I deleted unwanted rows, I  wrote the reduced data frame to csv with pandas, but output file size is larger than the original csv. why? and how I can reduce it.

I don't want to change file format.

```
buses.to_csv('simplified_matrix2.csv')
```

Comment: Any code you can show us ? Maybe you did something wrong ? Did you inspect the csv file to verify the columns were deleted ?

Comment: @nos hello I'm quite experienced with pandas, the shape is now around 7 milion. but the size increased.

Comment: What encoding do the input and output files use?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I dont know input file, but output is utf-8

Comment: @Gaff Different encodings can result in different file sizes. Also, have you checked that there isn't simply a lot of padding at the end of the file? (I have no idea why it might be there, but it's worth a quick check.)